# 為無為， 則無不治 translation of Dao De Jing

Tags: translation

these are to last lines of the third chapter of Dao De Jing.my question to the first line: Is the first 為 used in another meaning than the last one. I know what is 無為. Should I translate it: by 無為, there is no untreatment? sorry, if my translation is silly:)

Answer (score 4):

> Is the first 為 used in another meaning than the last one.

They have the same **literal meaning** of 'action', but very different **connotations**. Since you already know what 無為 is, you know the connotation of the word is much deeper than the sum of the two characters.

> How to translate it

By acting the non-action, nothing can't be treated/ruled.

Answer (score 1):

為無為：以無為的方式去做，即以順任自然的態度去處理事物。

無為(more detailed):不做任何違反自然規律、有損道德規範、違反社會法則，有害眾生的事.

Translation From Old Chinese:

以順任自然的態度去處理事物，那麼天下就無所不治了

Then translate it to English.

Do not translate 順任自然 into "Do anything you want." OR "Do nothing"

I think "Do anything you should." OR "Do anything you believe it's correct" is better.

Answer (score 1):

"無為" is an adjective describing the action ("為")
or it can be an adverb describing the way of acting/performing.

A clumsy translation I could think of:

When a person is able to harmonise his actions with the Nature such that no one can realise them, there is nothing he cannot accomplish.